# gitolite and ssh-agent. Access denied.

Tags: gitolite, ssh-agent

I have a gitolite set-up on server A and I am totally able to clone repositories from my local machine.

```
user@localmachine:$ git clone git@A:repo.git
```

Nevertheless, I am not able to clone the same repository from server B

```
user@B:$ git clone git@A:repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
R access for repo DENIED to user
(Or there may be no repository at the given path. Did you spell it correctly?)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have ForwardAgent activated in my ~/.ssh/config and ssh-add -l gives me exactly the same output on the local machine and on server B.

Does anyone know what can explain this ?

Comment: What does '`ssh git@A`' from server `B` as `user`? It should display a gitolite answer.

Comment: OK I know what happened. I forgot to remove the entry I used the made some tests towards A 
in /etc/hosts on B.

Comment: Ok, I have added an answer illustrating that case.

Answer (score 0):

The error the [OP user2819697](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2819697/user2819697) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177928/gitolite-and-ssh-agent-access-denied#comment28376971_19177928) has been seen before:

> I forgot to remove the entry I used the made some tests towards `A` in `/etc/hosts` on `B`.

You can see an /etc/hosts config in this [setting for Jenkins and Gitolite](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gitolite#Gitolite-add/etc/hostsentryforgitrepository):

> If the same IP hosts both gitolite and jenkins, you next want to add an entry to /etc/hosts for the git repository on the jenkins server.

```
 hesco@pbx:/var/lib/jenkins$ sudo vim /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       git.example.com git
```

So if anything on `B` `/etc/hosts` refers `A`... this cannot work well.